# How to execute an navigation fragment transaction after a navigation startActivity with an intent (deeplink) within a callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, navigation

i have to perform some kind of deep link, but my part of the project is an plugin, that gets hook over an interface. So i have no direct access to the navGraph and navController of the parent Project.
I can access the navigator over a callback. So I tried:

```
navigator.startActivtity(deepLinkFromTheParentProject)

navigator.fragmentAction { fragmentManager, containerId ->
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(containerId, MyFragmentToGo()).commit()
}
```

But it don't work I know, but how could i perfom this faki deeplink.

```
mycallbackNavigator -> 
val aNavIntent = mycallbackNavigator.startActivty(somedeepLink)
aNavIntent.fragmentAction{

fragmentManager, containerId ->
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(containerId, MyFragmentToGo()).commit()
}
```

Comment: My solution was, that I alway went to a desired location onBackStack